# Binding localized text with a link embedded in part of the text in Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a bit of a hairy localization question for Polymer.

Suppose I want to generate localized messages that have links within the message.  One raw example would be the following

```
<span>Join the <a href="http://some.url">Community</a>.</span>
```

So here, the full example the user sees would be "Join the Community." with "Community" as a nice link.  In non English locales, "Community" could show up in other positions in the message and in some locales there may not even be a period.

What would be the most effective way to do this with a generic element?

My though was to bind some text+html that comes from a localization process in some DOM node, such as:

```
<span>{{myLocalizedPromoWithLink}}</span>
...
myLocalizedPromoWithLink: 'Join the <a href="http://some.url">Community</a>.',
....
```

However data binding automatically sanitizes the string, as is usually the right thing to do. Can i somehow override this?

The other alternative is to create that the DOM node with the localized text and html directly with the raw string and inject it, but that sounds like a good attack vector.

Are there any other alternatives that don't involve Closure?  I'd rather avoid doing things like separate the localized string into the pre-link and post-link sections as that's really messy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "data binding automatically sanitizes the string"? Don't quite understand why you can't do as in your example. :o

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working:

```
   <dom-module id="my-element">

        <template>
            bla bla <span id="joinSpan">Join the __LINK__ Community __LINK__ something after</span> bla bla
        </template>

        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: "my-element",


                ready: function(){
                    console.log('my-element ready');
                    var spanContent = Polymer.dom(this.$.joinSpan).firstChild;
                    var parts = spanContent.textContent.split('__LINK__');

                    var link = document.createElement('a');

                    link.href='http://google.com/';
                    link.textContent = parts[1];

                    Polymer.dom(this.$.joinSpan).removeChild(spanContent);
                    Polymer.dom(this.$.joinSpan).appendChild(document.createTextNode(parts[0]));
                    Polymer.dom(this.$.joinSpan).appendChild(link);
                    Polymer.dom(this.$.joinSpan).appendChild(document.createTextNode(parts[2]));

                }

            });
        </script>

    </dom-module>
```

This is wrong:

What if put some special TOKEN instead of link into localized text and then substitue it with link, probably with computed property?
In localization property, or whatever, file:

Like 'Join the **LINK__BEGIN** Community **LINK_END**.'

then in component:

```
myLocalizedPromoWithLink: {
  type: String,
  computed: 'computeMyLocalizedPromoWithLink(myLocalizedPromoWithLinkRaw)'
} 

computeMyLocalizedPromoWithLink: function(myLocalizedPromoWithLinkRaw){
   var r = myLocalizedPromoWithLinkRaw.replace('__LINK__BEGIN__', '<a href="http://some.url">');
   r = r.repalce(replace('__LINK__END__', '</a>));

   return r
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that solves the problem? I'm pretty sure the problem is that the binding logic sanitizes the string before injecting it into the DOM.  So even a computed string would be sanitized.

Comment: yes, you're right the computed property is also sanitized, so I'd suggest to mangle with dom a bit. See updated answer